# Is there a piratebay for data(bases)? (here, talking about historical financial data)

Tags: market-data, data-mining, historical-data

I would like to, for example, access (and later, upload), for example, historical financial data for the S&P500.

If a piratebay for databases existed, maybe we could freely share information that deserves to be free already. Does such a site exist already? Mainly I'm just looking for financial data, but I'm developing data visualization software and would happily feast on as many datasets as I can download.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's nothing more stopping anyone from putting up a torrent of financial databases than there is from torrents of movies/tv/etc. That being said, this site is for professionals, which suggests the question is off-topic, at a minimum.

Comment: I would argue against closing.  While pirated databases may not be something we professionals deal in (to my knowledge) the possibility is nevertheless an interesting one.  At the same time, I would say answers giving pointers to pirated databases should be deleted.

Comment: @boulder_ruby you have any contact info? I'm local to you and have similar interests.

Answer (score 11):

No - clearly you've not seen the licensing agreements the exchanges force you to sign (one way or the other). Generally such firms and individuals have greater utility from the money they'll make working with the data than risking going to jail.

Market data is a 5bn / yr business. You're pushing the proverbial up-hill.

Anyway, you can get financial index data for free - with API access, no less, from sites as simple as Yahoo. Heck, if you're using R, you even get nice wrappers to the Yahoo Finance API via the `quantmod` package. That will cover most of your use case.

If you want good quality commercial data, it is stupid cheap from TickData and they have a nice db import front-end to make your life simple. The cost of the data is truly insignificant. Even for individuals / hobbyists. Comment: it will cost $98,800 for the whole package.

Comment: +1 for mentioning both billion dollar business and some free (but generally delayed access)  accessor functions. I have been standing the corresponding Perl / CPAN package [Finance::YahooQuote](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/yahooquote.html) for longer than I care to admit too :)

Comment: It is entirely conceivable that any day now, somebody could get a fix on edgar and start dumping free datasets online

Comment: i haven't changed my answer at all. i made some typo edits immediately after i posted the answer and haven't touched it since.

Comment: I wouldn't say tickdata.com is super cheap.  95K for only US TAQ is not super cheap for individuals or small funds.  Its just the cheapest there is.

Comment: @n.e.w - When you say "stupid cheap" what were you referring to ? After having a look around they are offering the full data for the FTSE for `$73,600.00` (past 13 years) and ` $12,000.00 ` for 1 year. - https://store.tickdata.com/prices?productMarketId=PRODUCT_MARKET.LSE

Comment: @n.e.w I'm guessing you have monied interests in the status quo of this situation. What you're saying is not true in all countries. It would only take a handful of collaborators to overcome this ridiculous industry. Oh, and by the way. price data isn't what I'm talking about. Financial data is the target here.

Comment: No, TickData is stupid expensive. What hobbyist has $100,000 knocking around for some data? In any case you did not answer the question at all, merely spewed an anti-piracy rant.